# Why a complete boolean statement is not required in if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am wondering why "if (ethos[name])" is already enough? Coz I would write if(name=ethos[name]). What does it mean? Thank you.

````
var ethos = {
    achilles: "glory",
    aeneas: "duty",
    hades: null // Beyond human understanding
}

function printEthos (name) {
    if (ethos[name]) {
        console.log(ethos[name]);
    } else {
        console.log(name + " has no recorded ethos.");
    }
}```
````

Comment: _"Coz I would write if(name=ethos[name])"_ - which most likely doesn't do what you think it does. `=` is the assignment operator, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Comment: The fact that `ethos[name]` contains a  value, causes the if condition to be `true`. If the value was null, empty string or 0, it would be `false`.

Comment: It works because JavaScript has the concept of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

Comment: `if(name=ethos[name])` arguably tests the same 'truthiness' of the value held in `ethos[name]` but also reassigns name to the value.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know why now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (esthos[name])` checks whether the the value held at `ethos[name]` is [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). To explicitly cast it to a `boolean`, you can do `if (!!esthos[name])`. The reason for this is that javascript uses `truthy` and `falsy` values.

[You can read more about it in this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: _"The reason for this is that javascript uses truthy values instead of real true and false"_ - That's not true... There are values that will be treated as `true`/`false` in specific conditions when used in a condition like `if (...)`

Comment: _"`if (esthos[name])` checks whether the variable contains a value."_ - That's not true. The value in `esthos[name]` will be evaluated. If `esthos[name]` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value then it will still be treated as `false` (or vice versa)

Comment: Updated my answer, no reason to be so hostile about it.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has 7 falsy values `0`, `0n`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `NaN`, and the empty string `''`. In your case, your `if` is returning `undefined`, which is one of the falsy values, because of this, `if (esthos[name])` is enough to evaluate the falsy condition.

`console.log(esthos[name]) //-> undefined`

or, as  @Titulum said...

`console.log(!!esthos[name]) //-> false`

In the same way, you can check if an array is empty only with `if(esthos.length)`:

```
const esthos = []

console.log(esthos.length) //-> 0 which is a falsy value
// or
console.log(!!esthos.length) //-> false
```

`if (esthos.length)` is enough, because this will return `0` which is one of the falsy values in JavaScript, or a number different than `0`, which is truthy.

Comment: You`re right @pilchard, made the correction. Thanks.

Comment: no worries, you were right that `if(esthos.length)` is enough, it's just that `console.log(esthos.length)` prints `0` even though it will evaluate to false in the `if()` statement.